# What DSP functionality is used for Direwolf?

Tags: dsp, direwolf

Direwolf is a sound card TNC for FX.25/AX.25 communications. Direwolf "Uses computer's "soundcard" and digital signal processing."

I checked [the code on github](https://github.com/wb2osz/direwolf) and found the dsp.h header file. It contains four functions including a window function, and two band pass filter functions. Surely these four functions are not enough to do the type of DSP Direwolf does.

So my question is what are ALL the functions and functionality used that constitutes Direwolf's entire DSP functionality. Citing Direwolf source files and or an accompanying high level explaination would be very welcome.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean; the `src/` directory is full of code, much of which is DSP functionality. Just because it's not in a header called `dsp.h` doesn't mean it's not DSP :) For example, there's multiple files called `demod_{modulation type}.c`: quite clearly, these probably contain DSP functionality. So:

Comment: The answer to "So my question is what are ALL the functions and functionality used that constitutes Direwolf's entire DSP functionality." is "all of direwolf's code." You'll, like anyone else, including the original authors, would have to read all the source code. This question is a tad broad as it can only be answered by "this is the original source code, as you've already linked to".